# How can I move cobalt content file to another path

Tags: cobalt

As we know, When compiling Cobalt, resource files are located in content directory of the output directory(ex: out/linux-x64x11_qa). we have to copy cobalt execution file and content directory in the same directory when running cobalt on another platform or path. but I want to manage the two files separately now, If I put cobalt execution file to directory A and put content to directory B, how can I change the content path in the source code?

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, you should modify your implementation of [SbSystemGetPath()](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/starboard/system.h#347) to return your custom Content directory whenever it is passed the parameter [kSbSystemPathContentDirectory](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/starboard/system.h#38) (by Cobalt).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've implemented this feature.